# Как закрыть в этом условии только одну категорию записей, а не все?

Tags: wordpress

```
// If user not logged, return 404 for posts page and feeds
        public function make_posts_page_private() {
            if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                // Posts page/feed - return 404
                if ( is_home() || is_feed() ) {
                    require TEMPLATEPATH . '/404.php';
                    exit;
                }
                // Any type of post - return 404
                if ( is_single() || is_archive() || is_category() || is_tag() || is_date() || is_author() || is_search() ) {
                    require TEMPLATEPATH . '/404.php';
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
```

как в этом условии изменить is_category() на категорию с ID 1 рубрики?
пыталась писать так is_category('1') или так in_category('1') - не помогло решить вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Тебе стоит убрать из скрипта другие условия и оставить только `is_category('1')`. Как бы ты туда не передал id - остальные условия будут все равно закрывать любой тип поста^-^

```
// If user not logged, return 404 for posts page and feeds
        public function make_posts_page_private() {
            if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                // Posts page/feed - return 404
                if ( is_home() || is_feed() ) {
                    require TEMPLATEPATH . '/404.php';
                    exit;
                }
                // Any type of post - return 404
                if ( is_category('1') ) {
                    require TEMPLATEPATH . '/404.php';
                    exit;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: в итоге все равно выводит 404 страницу, но не оставшиеся записи из других категорий

Comment: возможно условие надо менять require TEMPLATEPATH . '/404.php';

Comment: Или убрать еще и вот этот кусок `if ( is_home() || is_feed() ) {
                    require TEMPLATEPATH . '/404.php';
                    exit;
                }`

Comment: а не все. условие работает, но только если открывать конкретно ссылку на рубрику. а что делать чтобы на странице вывода всех записей, видны были записи других категорий?

Comment: @ViC страницу записей у тебя закрывает условие `is_home()`

Comment: зато если убрать условие if ( is_home() || is_feed() ) то на странице записей видны вообще все что есть из написанного, от этого тогда нет смысла работы плагина уже хах.

Comment: @ViC Чтоб исключить из списка записей посты определенной рубрики - тебе условие добавлять надо в цикл вывода этих записей

Comment: не вышло, такой код к примеру <?php if (in_category('1') && !is_user_logged_in() ) continue; ?> вызвал ошибку в теме

Comment: @ViC документацию почитай, как это делается

Comment: да уж не первый раз ставлю такое условие, работало. сейчас не устраивает синтаксис отчего то  syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Comment: он просто не может быть лишним или не достающим. на страницу темы добавлено только условие <?php if (in_category('1') && !is_user_logged_in() ) continue; ?> содержимое страницы и в конце для завершения условия <?php endif; ?>